# How to get the BLE advertisement (GAP) scanrecord in Xamarin with Monkey.Robotics to extract additional information to the device name?

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

We want to extract more than the device name from a BLE advertisement with Xamarin using the [Monkey.Robotics](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics) framework.

This excerpt of the BLEExplorer example gets a Device, which provides a string containing the device name:

```
adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        devices.Add (e.Device);
    });
};
```

We like to know if there is a way to get to the full payload of the GAP advertisement?

Comment: See also https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/issues/49#issuecomment-119924576

Comment: This link seems to only reference the RSSI values, is there a way to get to the additional advertising data?

Comment: Yep, that is actually my question (-,